# Angular 2 environment not working

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, environment, package.json

I have set up an angular 2 application with development fetching data from the local computer hence json-server and the production fetches from the live API.

I believed typing **"ng serve --environment=prod"** in the terminal would launch the app using the "environment.prod.ts", production file instead of the dev file.

However this is not the case, i see nothing that reflects the difference in settings in the preview.

Please can someone point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: use ng serve prod

Comment: try using this : `ng serve --env="prod"`.
If it works, you shouldn't see the `Angular is running in dev mode...` in the console

Comment: Did you used angular-cli?

Comment: Yes I am using angular-cli.

Comment: Thanks Alex but... ng serve --env="prod" did not work either

Comment: Rahul "ng serve prod" not working either

Comment: I mean what settings can effect this? I have checked and it seems all is in order

Comment: Tried "SET NODE_ENV=prod", with no prevail#

Comment: in your `.angular-cli.json` file, do you have the `environments.prod` set to the environment.prod.ts file?

Answer (score 2):

Did you use `ng serve --prod` or `ng serve --environment prod` or `ng serve -e prod`? Also, make sure in your `.angular-cli.json` file that "environments" has prod defined. Do note that the Angular CLI tool doesn't really do anything when generating the two environment ts files. They both have a boolean that is true if you use prod and false otherwise. If you didn't set anything in the environment files, you're not going to see any difference.

Finally, it seems that `ng serve --prod` may not be a good way to deploy your code https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5274

Comment: I am a fool... Ankit Saroch was closest... the problem was because the "environmentSource" and "environments" json values in the angular-cli.json were incorrectly